# How to prove that the order of addition does not matter?

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

The more precise version of my
question:

Let $(a_i)_{i=1}^n$
be a set of values
for which the commutative and
associative rules hold.

Let
$P$ be a permutation of
$\{1, 2, ..., n\}$.
($1 \le P(i) \le n$
and
$i \ne j
\implies
P(i) \ne P(j)
$)

Prove that
$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i
=\sum_{i=1}^n a_{P(i)}
$.

My idea on proving this is
to transform the sequence
by a series of
associative and commutative rule
applications
to a "normal" form
in which the sequence is sorted.
This sorted sequence has
the same sum as the
original sequence.
(This requires the result that
any sequence can be sorted
by a series of
transpositions.)

Since sorting the permuted sequence
gives the same "normal" form,
its sum is the same.

Another proof might be by induction on $n$.
This would also
seem to need
a "normal" form for the sequence.
The new element would be
inserted into the sequence
wherever the normal form
requires it to be.

Comment: I don't really see why you're concerned about this in the first place. You have a finite sum, so there's no barrier to rearranging the terms, and you know that $\{P(a) : a \in [n]\} = [n]$ (here, $[n] = \{1,\ldots,n\}$).

Comment: Quote : "the commutative rule holds" - so you don't have anything to prove... :)

Comment: First prove the “general associative property”: the outcome is independent on how we compute the binary sums (with a fixed order of the summands).  Then prove general commutativity for a transposition and recall that any permutation is a composition of transpositions.

Comment: No really there is nothing to prove here, as long as you say : "Let $(a_{i})$ be a set of values for which the commutative and associative rules hold." And if you don't say that, it's not always true : some groups are not commutative ones.

Comment: To prove the result formally, if need is felt, one should first of all  *define* $\sum_1^mb_i$. The usual definition is the recursive $\sum_1^{k+1} b_i=(\sum_1^k b_i)+b_{k+1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permutation group $S_n$ of $n$ elements is generated by the transposition $\tau = (12)$ and a cycle of length $n$, namely $\sigma = (123\cdots n)$. To prove what you want for a particular $n$, you just need to verify two identities:

- Swapping the first two elements (i.e. invariance under $\tau$ )
  $$(((a_1 + a_2) + a_3) + \cdots + a_n) = (((a_2 + a_1) + a_3 + \cdots + a_n )$$
- Shifting all elements to the right (i.e. invariance under $\sigma^{-1}$)
  $$(((a_1 + a_2) + a_3) + \cdots + a_n) = (((a_n + a_1) + a_2 + \cdots + a_{n-1})$$

The first identity is trivially true, it is just the commutativity between two elements $a_1$ and $a_2$.

For the second identity, assume you have proved the statement for any sum of $n-1$ elements. Treating $(a_1+a_2)$ as a single element and apply the assumed identity to the list of $n-1$ elements:
$$(a_1+a_2), a_3, a_4, \cdots a_n$$
We get

$$(((a_1 + a_2) + a_3 ) + a_4 + \cdots +  a_n))
= ((a_n + (a_1 + a_2)) + a_3  + \cdots + a_{n-1}))$$
By the ordinary associativity among the 3 elements $a_n, a_1, a_2$,
$$a_n + (a_1 + a_2) = (a_n + a_1) + a_2$$
the RHS can be transformed
$$(((a_n + a_1) + a_2) + a_3 + \cdots a_{n-1} )$$
This is precisely what we need for the second identity for the given $n$ to be true. Since the statement is trivially true for $n = 3$, by induction, the second identity is true for all $n \ge 3$.

Combine these two identities, we have established the general commutativity for finite sums defined recursively by following formula:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \stackrel{def}{=} 
\begin{cases} 
\displaystyle\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a_k \right) + a_n,& n > 1\\
\\
a_1, & n = 1
\end{cases}
$$

Please note that in this proof, we have not proved nor used general associativity at all.